# using AngularJS to control HTML button redirects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using a Bootstrap theme using Angular JS.
I have three menu buttons located at the top, all of which are going straight to the same page (users), But I would like them to redirect to other associated tabs. In my app.js I have the following routeProvider which should direct the buttons to other html/js files I have:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/users', {
            template: '<svn-userlist></svn-userlist>'
        }).
        when('/groups', {
        //  templateUrl: 'grouplist.html'
          template: '<svn-grouplist></svn-grouplist>'
        }).
        when('/repos', {
            template: '<svn-repolist></svn-repolist>'
        }).
        when('/users/:uid', {
            template: '<svn-userform></svn-userform>'
        }).
        when('/groups/:gid', {
            template: '<svn-groupform></svn-groupform>'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/users'
        });
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);
```

How can I setup this routeProvider so that it functions properly?

Comment: Read some basic tutorials about routeProvider and come back when you have an error. Try something before asking

Comment: You could try a more advanced version - [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router). It will help you to handle nested pages as well as the different tabs